# How to map over 2 arrays simultaneously and update the arrays according to condition in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In React,I am passing data from parent component to child component.Both the components have their own individual state which has an array of books.

I am passing the books array of the parent component to the child component.I can add a book from a child component to the parent component.

In the child component, I need to perform a condition : If the books array of child component has an element which is already present in the books array of the parent component,then I need to update one property of the books array in child component.

So,how  do I map over both the arrays and check my condition?

I was trying out with the below code and this doesn't work. I know the below code is not the correct way, but I am not able to figure out how to proceed

```
let parent_books = this.props.books;
  this.state.child_books.map((book,index) => {
      if(book === parent_books[index])
          book.shelf = parent_books[index].shelf

    })
```

So, the parent books array will have few books which are already there in the child books array.

So I want to check if the parent books array has a book which is present in child books array,then I want to set the shelf property for that in child books array to whatever the property of the book in parent books array.

All the books in child Component has an initial shelf property of "None".

Can anyone please suggest how to proceed with this?

**EDIT**

I am trying tom implement the code in the below function.But I am facing some issues while using setState. The code:

```
updateSearch = (searchString) => {
    let parent_books = this.props.books;
    this.setState({search: searchString.trim()})
    let searchResults = BooksAPI.search(this.state.search,1).then((book_search) => {
      if (book_search != undefined) {
        console.log(book_search)
          book_search.map((book) => book.shelf = 'none')
          this.setState({ books : book_search })
          console.log(this.state.books) //Gives the array of state
        }
    })

    console.log(this.state.books) //Gives an empty array
    this.state.books.map((book) => {
      const parent = parent_books.find(parent => parent === book );
      if(parent) {
        console.log(book.title);
        book.shelf = parent.shelf
      }
    })
  }
```

The second console.log is not returning the array of books in the state for which the map function after that is not being executed.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you wanting to simply output the correct `shelf` value in `render`, or do you want to update the child books state? If you'd like to update the child books state, then I'm assuming the code would live in the child component `componentWillReceiveProps()`? And in that case, you can `setState` with the result of the `map`.

Comment: @RickJolly I want to update both the child and parent book state which will make the component re-render.Actually I want to change the value of shelf for the book in child component if the book is present in the parent component.The books in parent component are in their respective shelves.And in the child component, initially all the books has a shelf property set to "none"

Comment: can you explain why you have states that can be apparent in both components? wouldn't it be a lot easier to keep the state in one place?

Comment: `map()` returns an array. You need to use `forEach()` and use `setState` to update the component's state

Comment: @azium Actually my parent compoent will make an API call where there will be books which are in their respective shelves by default.So, I have a used one state for that array of books.And in my child component ,I can search for a book and add the book to the shelf of parent component.Initially,in the child component, the books are not assigned to any shelf.So,I have used a separate state for the books array in the search component.The search component(Child component) will have all the books listed in the search result. From the search page,i can add a book to the parent component's shelf.

Comment: Note: you cannot edit the state directly on an component. and an child doesn't change it's parent. Instead, try to think that the child tells the parent to change, and the parent decide what to do. 
In your case, i think the best is to map every props before render. You can end on an crazy application state doing such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your use case, but something like this might work:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {parent_books} = this.props;
    const {child_books} = this.state;
    if (parent_books !== nextProps.parent_books) {
      const books = child_books.map((child) => {
        const parent = parent_books.find(parent => parent.id === child.id);
        if (parent) {
          child.shelf = parent.shelf
        }
        return child;
      })
      this.setState({child_books: books});
    }
}
```

Note that `parent_books` should be immutable so that `parent_books !== nextProps.parent_books` works. You wouldn't likely want to use `index` as a lookup (I'm using a fictional id in the example) since parent books and child books order would have to stay in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I tried to implement your answer . But I am facing some issues.I have mentioned the issue in an Edit for the question above.Also,I have mentioned the problem as comment in the code. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous so you can't access `this.state.something` after a `setState` and expect it to be updated. However, `setState` does take an optional callback as a second argument if you need.

Comment: You're not using `map` correctly. Also, you can't do an equality check like `parent === book` since that would always return false since they're not the same object references.

Comment: okay,thank you.I will try to make the changes accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to update the state of the component, you need to use `setState`. Also, `map` returns an array so instead, use `forEach`;

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.state.child_books.forEach((book, i) => {
    if(book === parent_books[i]){
      this.setState({child_books: {shelf: [parent_books[i].shelf]}});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try it out and see if it works.